# Select layer by attribute using expression qtcreator/pyqgis

Tags: python, pyqgis, qt-designer

I'm trying to make a function like ArcGIS's select using Python 3.6 , QGIS 2.8.6 and QtDesigner, so this is my code:

```
def execute(self):
        layers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers()
        selectedLayerIndex = self.dlg.layers.currentText()        
        layer=None
        for lyr in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
            if lyr.name() == selectedLayerIndex:
                layer = lyr                
                qgis.utils.iface.setActiveLayer(layer)
                expr = QgsExpression(" \"BORONAME\" = 'The Bronx'")
                it = layer.getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest( expr ) )
                ids = [i.id() for i in it]
                layer.setSelectedFeatures( ids )
                self.dlg.expression.setText(" ")
                self.dlg.lineEdit.setText(" ")
            break
```

I'm choosing a layer that has an attribute called "BORONAME" with the value 'The Bronx' when I try the code on Python console plugin it works fine, the results shown selected, but I got nothing when I use the plugin that I created.

Comment: Please consider to port this directly to QGIS 3. QGIS 2 is not so much supported anymore.

Comment: It looks ok to me. Try to put some print messages into the execute function and then check if that statement pops out in QGIS python console. Then you know if that code is executed from plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just had to turn the 'break' to the if level

```
layers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers()
        selectedLayerIndex = self.dlg.layers.currentText()        
        layer=None
        for lyr in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
            lyr.removeSelection()
            if lyr.name() == selectedLayerIndex:
                layer = lyr                
                expression =str(" \"BORONAME\" = 'The Bronx'")
                expr = QgsExpression(expression)
                it = layer.getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest( expr ) )
                layer.setSelectedFeatures( ids )
                self.dlg.expression.setText(" ")
                self.dlg.lineEdit.setText(" ")     
                self.iface.mapCanvas().zoomToSelected()
                break
```